# Which library i can use for uploading file (doc, pdf, txt, etc.) in react-native?

Tags: file, react-native

I want library like image-picker for uploading files which library i can use for uploading files(doc, pdf, txt, etc.). it should work on iphone and android (cross platform). please suggest me best library for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am guessing you have to open a file in react native so that you can access that file in the app.
If so you can use this library to achieve the same:

https://github.com/huangzuizui/react-native-file-opener

It works for both ios and android and we have used it in production without any issue as of now.